# Cordova - should be updated to support ios11

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I have a cordova app using cordova version 6.4.0

Apple posted note to developers, all apps or updates starting July 2018 should be built with ios 11 sdk([details here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/))

My question is: If I submit an update to app after July 2018, should app be build against cordova version 8.0? or can I continue using cordova version 6.4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer your Cordova CLI version is, the easier it will be to compile your app with Xcode and upload it to the store later. But it may cause problems with old plugins, so always uninstall and reinstall every plugin one by one after updating the CLI.

You may use **any** Cordova version, as the compilation job is done by Xcode after all, but Apple forces developers to use latest Xcode versions in order to deploy in newer iOS versions. Therefore, you should use latest CLI version, as long as your plugins are compatible. The older your CLI version is, the greater your problems to create the iOS app will be, said master Yoda.

Answer (score 1):

To build using iOS 11 SDK you need to build the app with Xcode 9.

As far as I remember, the Cordova 6.4.0 CLI had some issues with building the apps in Xcode 9, so it's recommended to update the CLI. But it's not really needed as you can open the native project in AppName/platforms/ios/ and manually build the app from Xcode 9 instead of using the CLI.

You will also need to add some missing images (icons and launch images) that the old CLI won't be generating/copying.

Comment: Installation and updating of plugins DOES depend heavily on the current Cordova version. You can't simply "forget" about Cordova and keep using xCode forever, this is not possible with Cordova apps if you plan to keep them up-to-date.

Comment: @andreszs the question says nothing about plugins, if he doesn't want to update Cordova, he probably doesn't want to update plugins neither. Anyway, the only core plugin updated for iOS 11 is statusbar plugin, which is compatible with any cordova version. But of course, it's always recommended to use latest version of everything, just saying that it's not mandatory.